# BTRFS error (device sda1): couldn't find block (456420491264) (level 1) in tree (7) with key (5764 84 3725675564) during balance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, btrfs

I have a 2 TB btrfs drive that is pretty full. While running `btrfs balance start -musage=90` I got this error:

> BTRFS error (device sda1): couldn't find block (456420491264) (level 1) in tree (7) with key (5764 84 3725675564)

Log:

```
Dez 10 12:33:19 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): balance: start -musage=90 -susage=90
Dez 10 12:33:19 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): relocating block group 2130334187520 flags system|dup
Dez 10 12:33:20 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): found 11 extents, stage: move data extents
Dez 10 12:33:20 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): relocating block group 1951019302912 flags metadata|dup
Dez 10 12:33:23 kernel: BTRFS error (device sda1): couldn't find block (456420491264)Dez 10 12:33:19 p-zenbook kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): balance: start -musage=90 -susage=90
Dez 10 12:33:19 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): relocating block group 2130334187520 flags system|dup
Dez 10 12:33:20 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): found 11 extents, stage: move data extents
Dez 10 12:33:20 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): relocating block group 1951019302912 flags metadata|dup
Dez 10 12:33:23 kernel: BTRFS error (device sda1): couldn't find block (456420491264) (level 1) in tree (7) with key (5764 84 3725675564)
Dez 10 12:33:50 kernel: BTRFS info (device sda1): balance: ended with status: -2
 (level 1) in tree (7) with key (5764 84 3725675564)
```

I then ran `btrfsck --progress --readonly /dev/sda1` I got several errors while step 2 (checking extends):

```
owner ref check failed [2111302246400 73728]
ref mismatch on [2111302590464 16384] extent item 1, found 0
incorrect local backref count on 2111302590464 parent 1052858761216 owner 0 offset 0 found 0 wanted 1 back 0x55d9a8c3e720
backref disk bytenr does not match extent record, bytenr=2111302590464, ref bytenr=0
backpointer mismatch on [2111302590464 16384]
owner ref check failed [2111302590464 16384]
ref mismatch on [2111342129152 966656] extent item 15, found 12
incorrect local backref count on 2111342129152 parent 1052858761216 owner 0 offset 0 found 0 wanted 1 back 0x55d9a8c459c0
backref disk bytenr does not match extent record, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytenr=0
backref bytes do not match extent backref, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytes=966656, backref bytes=4096
incorrect local backref count on 2111342129152 parent 1052519825408 owner 0 offset 0 found 0 wanted 1 back 0x55d9a8c45960
backref disk bytenr does not match extent record, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytenr=0
backref bytes do not match extent backref, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytes=966656, backref bytes=4096
incorrect local backref count on 2111342129152 parent 570294272 owner 0 offset 0 found 0 wanted 1 back 0x55d9a8c45900
backref disk bytenr does not match extent record, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytenr=0
backref bytes do not match extent backref, bytenr=2111342129152, ref bytes=966656, backref bytes=4096
backpointer mismatch on [2111342129152 966656]
```

**As there are several warnings about [`btrfsck --repair`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-check.html): is it recommended to run it in this case?**

kernel 5.15.0-56-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu
btrfs-progs v5.4.1